# Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade issue issue

Tags: upgrade

I'm was running Ubuntu 15.10 on vsphere ESXi. I upgraded to 16.04 and now it gets stuck once I try to log in or nothing happens (can't get to desktop). Its weird cause all the services work I can log in SSH thru putty and I can reach my apache website so I don't think its frozen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you try adding a new user and checking if the desktop works for that one?